# gcc cannot find winedef.h for wow64 build of wine 6.2

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, wine

I compiled the wine 6.2 with wow64 build instructions: https://wiki.winehq.org/Building_Wine#Shared_WoW64

Everything seemed to work fine except when I tried to install wineasio and playonlinux, gcc could not import windef.h (`fatal error: windef.h: No such file or directory`).

The file exists in `/usr/local/include/wine/windows/` and I tried adding it to my path but gcc still could not find the file.

Comment: Is the file name in the same case ?

Comment: yes, and I'm using manjaro gnu/linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved /usr/local/include/wine/ to /usr/include/. It's fixed now.